# ActionScript: Draw a border around a masked image?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm trying to write some ActionScript which will accept a mask and an image, then mask the image and put a border around the result (assuming that the mask is always 100% opaque).

For example, if my mask is a poorly drawn star, and my image is a bunch of flowers, I want the result to be a poorly drawn star with flowers inside it and a border around it. Something like this:

[masked flowers http://img.skitch.com/20100120-xghntrn5yumxst97gjky2qje1p.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100120-xghntrn5yumxst97gjky2qje1p.png)

Is that possible? And, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that is not possible. I would think about using a GlowFilter on the masked image and setting its properties so that it looks like a border.

Comment: Cool - I was able to sort of fake it using a GlowFilter with `strength=8` and `inner=true`. It's not perfect, though (can't get rounded corners, the size is sometimes inconsistent, etc) :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the Glow Filter idea TBH... But **where is that mask coming from?** Depending on that answer I have two ideas:

**If it's coming from user input**, as in, a user is drawing a shape WITHIN the flash app, then it's pretty easy:

1. You would record an array of points while the user was "drawing" the shape.
2. Then you create and draw two movie clips

   - One with a fill that would be the mask.
   - And another with an outline that would be the outline to go over the mask.

**If it's coming from outside the flash app**, it's *possible*, but it would be **slower than dirt**. You could:

1. Take the mask movie (assuming it's all black) and convert it to a Bitmap object.
2. Then step through the bitmask object, pixel by pixel, to determine the outer points of the object.
3. Then the not so easy part (LOL): Then step through all of the points and reorganize them so the they're all next to the two closest points to them in the array.
4. Then you could create a new movie and draw the points as lines on that movie, placing it in a layer above the mask.

Comment: Ah, good point. I will be creating the masks, so creating a "sibling" which contains just the border wouldn't be out of the question. Thanks for the suggestions.